# Proof verification: $\{f<g\}$ is a measurable set.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $f,g: \mathbb X \to \mathbb R$ be two measurable functions. Prove
> $\{f<g\}=\{x \in \mathbb X | f(x) < g(x) \}$ is a measurable set.

I think this is a pretty basic proof but I would appreciate some help verifying my attempt:

Define $h=f-g$. Then $h$ is also measurable. We have:

$$ 
\{x \in \mathbb X | f(x) < g(x) \} = \{x \in \mathbb X | h(x)<0\} = h^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,0\right)\right)
$$

Since $(-\infty,0)$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$ and $h$ is measurable, $h^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,0\right)\right) = \{f<g\}$ is a measurable set.

Comment: I think its alright

Comment: Sure, looks right... but note it sweeps all the difficulty into the proof that a sum of two measurable functions is measurable (not necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: Why is $f-g$ measurable? Do you have a link?